# rails google-api-client contact api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, contacts

I want to get access to a user's contact list with the google contacts API.
I've managed to get the token and refresh token and I'm now trying to use then on my rails server.
The `google-api-client` gem seems to be the way to go but I could not find which `discovered_api` to use. Greg Baugues provides a great [tuto](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/12/sms-alerts-for-urgent-emails-with-twilio-and-the-gmail-api.html) to get the gmail API working. The general request seems to look like

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.access_token = user_token
service = client.discovered_api('gmail')
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => service.users.labels.list,
  :parameters => {'userId' => 'me'},
  :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
pp JSON.parse(result.body)
```

But I could not find how to query it for contacts. Running

```
client.discovered_apis.each do |gapi|
  puts "#{gapi.title} \t #{gapi.id} \t #{gapi.preferred} \n"
end
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474720/determining-the-parameters-for-discovered-api)) shows now API related to contacts and I'm wondering if this is implemented in the alpha version of the gem...

Comment: Did you think about use some ready solutions, like [ruby google contacts api](https://github.com/aliang/google_contacts_api) or [cloudsponge for ruby](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/ruby)?

Comment: I could not find them... All the search results were pointing to /developers.google.com. They work great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index) is on Google's older GData API standard and is not supported by the discovery API. There is a pretty [extensive guide for plain Ruby](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_ruby) and a [helper gem](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-ruby-util/). [Retrieving all contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index#retrieving_all_contacts) doesn't provide a Ruby sample but the Python sample should translate pretty easily.

```
def PrintAllContacts(gd_client):
  feed = gd_client.GetContacts()
  for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
    print '\n%s %s' % (i+1, entry.name.full_name.text)
    if entry.content:
      print '    %s' % (entry.content.text)
    # Display the primary email address for the contact.
    for email in entry.email:
      if email.primary and email.primary == 'true':
        print '    %s' % (email.address)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @abraham, the Google contact API is not supported by the discovery API. Here is how I did it in ruby from the access token using the gems `google_contacts_api` and `oauth2` (thanks to [Rael Gugelmin Cunha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1604312/rael-gugelmin-cunha) for pointing them to me):

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, site: url)
token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, access_token)
google_contacts_user = GoogleContactsApi::User.new(token)
contacts = google_contacts_user.contacts
```

There might be some more elegant way to do it but this works :)